# Android BLE 4.0 BluetoothLeScanner ScanCallback onScanResult is called several time

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-5.0-lollipop, android-bluetooth

My app is scanning a Bluetooth 4.0 advertising device (TI SensorTag) via the new Lollipop API `BluetoothLeScanner`.

I've got a strange behavior: On certain devices (Samsung Tab4, Sony Xperia M2), the callback `void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result)` is only called 1 time during the advertising phase. On other devices (Samsung Galaxy Tab A, Acer Iconia  One 10), the callback is always called: each time I got an advertising packet.

My straightforward code:

```
public class BluetoothMgr {

    private static BluetoothMgr mBluetoothMgr = null;

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private BluetoothLeScanner mBluetoothLeScanner;    

    private BluetoothMgr(){
        BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager) DeviceLiftApplication.getContext().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = manager.getAdapter();
        mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    }    

    public static synchronized BluetoothMgr getInstance(){
        if(mBluetoothMgr == null){
            mBluetoothMgr = new BluetoothMgr();
        }

        return mBluetoothMgr;
    }

    public void startScan() {
        ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder()
                //.setServiceUuid(Device.THERM_SERVICE)
                .build();
        ArrayList<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
        filters.add(filter);

        ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                .build();

        mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
    }

    private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            // This is called 1 or several times depending on devices!!
            processResult(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            for (ScanResult result : results) {
                processResult(result);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {

        }

        private void processResult(ScanResult result) {

        }
    };

}
```

Comment: and the question is?  this is annoying but it is the way things are at present.

Comment: Just wondering which is the normal behavior. Because in the multi-notification case, I would be able to detect the presence or absence of the advertising device.

Comment: both are normal depending on the device you are on.  You need to code up to support both.  If you want multiple it means starting ad stopping the scan all the time.  If you want one just add in your own layer to remove the duplicates.

Comment: Ok I will do this, thank you very much for your help.